# Understand wcf security in depth

Tags: wcf-security

I am trying to understand WCF security.

The issue I am facing is that I find a very high level of abstraction in WCF. I would really liek to know how things work under the wire. Like when I studied netTCPBinding I had a query of how encryption is achieved in this binding.

But it has been really difficult to get that kind of information.

Could you suggest a book or reference material which details the WCF security model ? rather than talking about it at 5000 ft altitude

Comment: try this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms788756.aspx